# php zlib: How to dynamically create an in-memory zip files from string variables?

Tags: php, dynamic, zip, zlib

this is what I need

```
$a=array('folder'=>'anyfolder','filename'=>'anyfilename','filedata'=>'anyfiledata');
```

I need to create a variable $zip with compressed data from $a and output this $zip into browser window with

```
header('Content-type: application/octetstream');
echo $zip;
```

All libs that I found, they pack files and create zip files physically on disk. I need to do it dynamically, using memory. Is there any examples of how to do it using pure php's zlib and without studying the zip format specifications?

UPD:
could it be done with [CreateZIP](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2322-PHP-Create-ZIP-file-archives-and-serve-for-download.html) class?

UPUPD:
Yes. it could =)

Comment: A simple solution would be to create a ramdisk with tmpfs and handle your zips in there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [CreateZIP](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2322-PHP-Create-ZIP-file-archives-and-serve-for-download.html) class does it.

```
require_once('CreateZipFile.php');
$zip = new CreateZipFile;
$zip->addFile('anyfiledata', 'anyfilename');
$zip->addFile('anyfiledata2', 'anyfolder/anyfilename.anyext');
$zip->addDirectory('anyemptydirwouldbecreatedinthiszipfile');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.'zipfile.zip'.'');
header('Content-type: application/octetstream');
echo $zip->getZippedfile();
die();
```

great thanx to **Er. Rochak Chauhan**